# I'm unsure where to fix my code and where the potential mistake may be

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_factors = web.DataReader(['GDP','DSPIC', 'IPDMAT', 'CUSR0000SAD', 'PCU33523353','UNRATE','DFF'],'fred', start_date, end_date)

df_factors = pd.DataFrame(df_factore.values, index=pd.PeriodIndex(df_factors.index, freq='M'), columns = {'GDP','DSPIC', 'IPDMAT', 'CUSR0000SAD', 'PCU33523353','UNRATE','DFF'})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to python

Answer (score 0):

If need convert `DatetimeIndex` to `PeriodIndex` use [`DataFrame.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_period.html):

```
df_factors = web.DataReader(['GDP','DSPIC', 'IPDMAT', 'CUSR0000SAD', 'PCU33523353','UNRATE','DFF'],'fred', start_date, end_date)

df_factors = df_factors.to_period('M')
```

Or use [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
df_factors.index = df_factors.index.to_period('M')
```

Comment: As a result when I go to print out my table, it shows it up with daily frequency over monthly.

Comment: @BotBotsworth - hmmm. So what your code should do? I cannot find information. Do you need aggregate `mean` and convert daily datetimeIndex to month periodIndex? Or something else?